# Typescript: How to invoke class function from anonymous function - property does not exist on type

Tags: angular, typescript

There is a service is defined as below:

```
export class MyService {
    doSomething(callbacks: { onSuccess: (data: Object) => any, onError: (err: any) => any }) {
        // This function does something
    }
}
```

It is used in a component as below:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    someFunction(): void { 
        this.myService.doSomething(
            {
                onSuccess(data: Object) {
                    onSuccessFunction(data) // Error here
                },
                onError(err: any) {
                }
            }
        )
    }
    
    onSuccessFunction(data: Object) {
    }
}
```

As can be seen above, the `onSuccessFunction` which is defined in `MyComponent` and invoked in the anonymous function `onSuccess`. But still typescript is giving error as below:

```
Property 'initActiveOrders' does not exist on type '{ onSuccess: (data: Object) => any; onError: (err: HttpErrorResponse) => any; }'.ts(2339)
```

What can be the possible reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
someFunction(): void { 
  this.myService.doSomething({
    onSuccess: (data: Object) => {
      this.onSuccessFunction(data);
    },
    ...
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot to add `this.` before the method-call on line 5

Comment: Please see the edited question. It is looking for the function inside the anonymous function.